# How can I align my text and put the button on the extrem right of my gray bar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

how can I display my Invitee2 a bit upper in my gray bar ? And for my button how can I put it on the extrem right side of my gray bar ?

```
<div className="bg-gray-200 p-5 h-5 pl-2 mb-2 text-md text-primary-500  font-bold  text-gray-500">
Invitee {i + 1}
<span className="float-right -mt-5">
    {!!i && (
        <Button primary className="rounded-md float-right mt-4" onClick={() => removeInvitee(pId)}>
            - Invitee
        </Button>
    )}
</span>
```

And `Button.jsx`:

```
export default function Button({ onClick,primary,children,disabled }) {
    return <button
        onClick={onClick}
        className={`${primary
            ? ' cursor-pointer rounded-md bg-primary-700 py-2 px-3  text-white  hover:bg-blue-700 hover:text-white'
            : 'bg-transparent  text-gray border border-primary-500 hover:border-primary-100 hover:text-primary-100 transition duration-200 '} 
            text-primary-fg py-2 px-3 rounded-md transition-colors `}
        disabled={disabled}
    >{children}</button>
}
```

Here a picture to get the idea :[image: picture]

Answer (score 1):

Add `flex flex-row justify-between items-center` in your `div` class

and remove the `-mt-5` in `span` class beside `float-right`

check the code below

```
<div className="flex flex-row justify-between items-center bg-gray-200 p-5 h-5 pl-2 mb-2 text-md text-primary-500  font-bold  text-gray-500">
Invitee {i + 1}
  <span className="float-right">
      {!!i && (
          <Button primary className="rounded-md float-right mt-4" onClick={() => removeInvitee(pId)}>
              - Invitee
          </Button>
      )}
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, `Invitee2` is well placed but `- Invitee` is not at the end of my gray bar

Comment: play around with your padding (The `p-{n}` or `pl-{n}`) inside your `function Button`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the flexbox properties to make the design you want. I had created the very similar example below , please add your functions here and replace `class` with `className`.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="container mx-auto py-4">
<div class="bg-gray-200 text-md flex items-center justify-between rounded-r-md">
  <div class=" font-bold  text-gray-500 ml-4" >Invitee 2</div>
  <div class="">
    <Button primary class="rounded-md bg-black text-white py-2 px-4" onclick="removeInvitee(pId)">
        - Invitee
    </Button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, Is it normal that it works fine for all the Invitee>1. Because for Invitee1 the height of my gray bar is not the same as Invitee2 or Invitee3. See [here](https://www.linkpicture.com/q/invitee1.png) please